# Is there a way to use EF7 with a non-dnx project?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

My current solution has a web project, which I'm using as a class library to generate all my csharp models in a database-first way.

I like EF7's code scaffolder, and there was a bug fixed recently that would solve the problem I'm having right now with EF6, and crappy navigation property naming.

such as:

```
UserId_CreatedBy => User
UserId_ModifiedBy => User1
UserId_Owner => User2
```

So, I guess, at the bare minimum is there a way I could scaffold classes from my database and use them in a non-dnx project?

Comment: I'm curious about your EF6 "crappy naviagation property naming" issue

Comment: Also, have you seen [the example targeting .NET Framework 4.5.1](http://ef.readthedocs.org/en/latest/platforms/full-dotnet/existing-db.html)?

Comment: @Moho it happens when a table has multiple references to another table. In my example, say a `Books` table has 3 references to the user table, as in my question, then the resulting navigation properties are generated...

Comment: You are aware you can configure their naming via data annotation attributes or fluent API?

Comment: @Moho, I specifically stated I'm using database-first, and everything is generated. There are 400+ models, I'm not customizing data annotation attributes or using the fluent API.